# How to get random rows with special condition in R

Tags: r

Hello how can I get 2 random rows with special condition. The example below are dates and I want to get a random sample of 2 dates with any year but month and day is 12/31. So it's like "XXXX1231".

```
> dateDS
    dateDS
1 20121231
2 20131020
3 20140819
4 20151231
5 20161231
6 20171106
7 20131231
```

And I want to get a random sample that would output 2 dates ("XXXX1231")

```
> dateSample
    dateSample
1 20121231
2 20131231
```

Answer (score 4):

One way using `grep` find indices of dates which ends with "1231" and then subset them.

```
df[sample(grep("1231$", df$dateDS), 2), ,drop = FALSE]

#    dateDS
#5 20161231
#4 20151231
```

Or if you want just values of those dates and don't want to subset

```
sample(grep("1231$", df$dateDS, value = TRUE), 2)
#[1] "20151231" "20161231"
```

---

Another option, convert the `dateDS` to actual date extract month and date and randomly select two values with "1231" in it.

```
df$dateDS[sample(which(format(as.Date(as.character(df$dateDS), "%Y%m%d"), "%m%d") == "1231"), 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option with `substr()` in order to select only dates with `1231`, then `sample` two rows:

```
d <- read.table(text="dateDS
20121231
                20131020
                20140819
                20151231
                20161231
                20171106
                20131231", header=T)

d$md <- substr(d$dateDS, 5, 8) # use md to select only "1231"
d <- d[d$md==1231, ]
# d    ateDS   md
# 1 20121231 1231
# 4 20151231 1231
# 5 20161231 1231
# 7 20131231 1231
d[sample(2), -2]
#[1] 20151231 20121231
```